# Script to indent actionscript 3 files?

Tags: actionscript-3

Are there any scripts to auto-indent an actionscript 3 file?  I want to standard the check-in to source control, and this way, it'll be uniform (instead of mixing spaces and tabs).  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Flex Formatter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flexformatter/) provided you have the Flex Eclipse IDE. Also read [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=code_editor_5.html).

Comment: There is also a port of Flex Formatter for Flash Develop. http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=5208